# Can I host index.html (homepage) on the Rackspace CloudFiles CDN?

Tags: performance, node.js, cdn, rackspace, singlepage

I want to make my web app fast, especially the first page load (index.html).

Can I do this by hosting myfastapp.com on Rackspace CloudFiles and then have a subdomain called nodeserver.myfastapp.com which connects to a Node Server on Joyent.

Note:  The node server will only connect via socket.io to tell the client which additional files to grab from the CDN (myfastapp.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a guide for this in the Cloud Files docs at [Create Static Website](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_Static_Website-dle4000.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Actually, I had a discussion with Rackspace customer service and they said the same thing.  I used UPCS [link](https://github.com/chmouel/upcs).  The key is to remember to set the mimeType using -C "text/css" (or whatever) when using UPCS.  Similar mimeType settings will apply to other CLI tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with that the logistics of that.

The main issue is getting the main site on Cloud Files due to cname restrictions, at least in the Rackspace system, but it can probably be done.